# Docusign recipient view url expires after 5 minutes

Tags: docusignapi

When a user clicks a button I'm generating multiple recipient views url. It's working, but after 5 minutes I get event=ttl_expired. I tried increasing the duration adding notification in the request:
`"notification": {"expirations": {"expireAfter": 3,"expireEnabled": true},"useAccountDefaults": false}`
Can it be increased the ttl_expired ? Or it needs a new recipient view url after the old one expired? If yes how should the flow look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Notifications -> Expirations parameter only applies to Envelope expiration. The Recipient View URL expiration cannot be extended beyond the 5 minute limit.

The workflow should be that the URL is only generated when the recipient's identity is verified and they are immediately ready to sign the envelope.

Comment: And if I have multiple recipient's  annd I generate just once a url for each of them?

Comment: How do you verify a recipient's identity?

Comment: Yes, if you have multiple recipients, they'll each need their own signing URL.

Comment: Verifying your recipient's identity in an Embedded Signing workflow is entirely on your application. If you'd like DocuSign to handle it, remove the ClientUserId and an email will be delivered that contains a link they can use to sign.